# Counters.Counter vs totalSupply

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

Creating my first contract and was taking a look at the Open Zeppelin wizard. I notice that it includes a  `Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;`, which tracks the amount of tokens minted. When I add the enumerable library it still seems to include that snippet within the code when there is now a `totalSupply` variable that seems to track the same value.

Question: Why is _tokenIdCounter included, and is there any difference between that and the totalSupply variable? Seems as though totalSupply would work fine and I should remove the _tokenIdCounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface they may sound the same.

Each NFT typically has an unique ID, and the Counters are used to assign the next available ID to a new NFT. This goes hand in hand with `totalSupply` as long as NFTs are minted.

However, if there is functionality to burn an NFT, the Counter doesn't decrease (since the IDs shouldn't typically be reused), but the `totalSupply` goes down.

Furthermore, I'm unsure if such functionality is ever desired, but at least in theory you *can* have two NFTs with the same ID - in which case the Counter is not in sync with `totalSupply` also.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So in the case that your NFT is not burnable, then the counter wouldn't be needed correct?

Comment: I guess. You need to analyze the contract and make sure

Comment: And the counter solution does not need so much gas to deploy

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference as `totalSupply` simply returns the length of the enumerated tokens array, which is [decremented on burn](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol#L85) and incremented on mint.